# Co-mingling "default" data with user-supplied data in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I know Apple will reject apps that backup data that can be reloaded from the app bundle.  However, in the app I'm working on, we'll be providing some basic data that users will want to keep in the Core Data store along with the new data they have created and entered.  So, users will use the "library" data we provide by integrating it with their own data as they work with the app.

My concern is whether Apple will require me to segregate these data in some way such that data from the bundle is not backed up to iCloud?  Once the data are co-mingled, disaggregation would be complex and burden the app excessively.

So, my question is whether I have to concern myself with the co-mingling of user data with that data which is supplied in the app bundle?

TIA for any input on this as I've not found anything about it in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar situation in my app. It has sample data, but the sample data is designed to be edited by the user, and has metadata attached to it that is user specific. In other words, the data is mutable, and belonged with the rest of the user's personally created data.

At one point, the app was rejected. I first appealed to the reviewer, explaining that the data was mutable, and personal to the user — it would not be possible to reproduce the data purely from the app bundle. The reviewer would not budge, so I appealed, and they sided with the reviewer. Game over.

You may be able to get away with a small amount of data loaded from your bundle (<1MB). If you plan to include images or anything that will push up that amount, they will likely reject you.

I also heard from another developer rejected for including data downloaded from a web service in the user's store. Apple claimed that the data could be re-downloaded, which may be partially true, but ignores the fact that the web service was operated by a third party, and the downloaded data could be unshared at any time. It also ignores that the user can edit the downloaded data, and that the client app is attaching user-specific metadata that cannot be downloaded.

That developer was rejected as well. He eventually got the app through review by introducing a complex set of procedures to import the data: the user had to first download the data to a temporary holding area that was not backed up. They then had to explicitly import the data, and dismiss a wordy dialog warning that the imported data would contribute to their iCloud backup quota. Horrible. But that is apparently what Apple wants.

The rule is pretty mindless, in my view, and Apple seem to be completely oblivious to the implications in terms of user interface changes and drastic refactoring of an app's model. I can't imagine any engineers were involved in forming the rule, because they surely would have realized how much unnecessary complexity it would impose on developers. We can only hope they see reason at some point.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear, but exactly the response I needed.  I think I'll have to rework what I was planning to do.  Thanks for the excellent answer.  This looks like a problem for in-app purchases of content, as well, which will get merged with the user-data.  Agree with your comment in the last paragraph; makes no sense at all.